# announced that . . . shed/has shed light

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

In the following sentence, should "shed" or "has shed" be used?

> Scientists **announced** on Wednesday that the drug **shed**/**has shed** new light on the treatment of amnesia.

Comment: Neither are at all likely. It would be much more natural here to say *Scientists announced on Wednesday that the drug [**sheds** new light on the treatment of amnesia.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sheds+new+light+on+the+treatment+of%22) There really is no good reason for using Past Tense at all here, let alone Past Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Either is grammatical, but `has shed` is probably preferred, because it implies that the shedding of new light has been happening over a period of time. Just `shed` technically refers to a single event that happened in the past, which is a possibility. For example, say there was a clinical trial for the drug; it's possible the drug during this trial (a single event) shed new light.

In casual English, either would be fine. In formal English, you probably want to use `has shed`.